# applying list of functions to list in common lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp, higher-order-functions

I have a list of functions, a list of elements, and I'd like to apply all the functions on all the elements then append all the resulting lists together. I did it as follow

```
(defun apply-functions(funcs elements)
    (if (null funcs)
        nil
        (append (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (funcall (car funcs) x)) elements) (apply-functions (rest funcs) elements))))
```

It works as intended, but I don't like it. Is there a cleaner, more concise way of doing it?. I am new to lisp, and still getting used to the lispish style of doing things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you like `loop` macro (and I don't want to spoil anyone), but try this:

```
(defun apply-functions (fs es)
    (loop for f in fs appending (mapcar f es)))
```

Comment: Haven't used loop before, but it looks great. I'll read on that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6):

This is the same idea as yours, just shorter:

```
(defun apply-functions (functions elements)
  (mapcan #'(lambda (x) (mapcar x elements)) functions))
```

Comment: This is nice, (car x) is not necessary here though, right?..shouldn't it just be mapcar x elements ?

Comment: how about using mapcan instead of mapcon? That should get rid of the (car x), and instead just have x.

Comment: This version is very nice. Is this more efficient than the looping version?

Answer (score 4):

I would define a function, `call-each` that returns a new function,
returning the list of calling each function on it's argument:

```
(defun call-each (fns)
  (lambda (arg)
    (mapcar (lambda (fn)
              (funcall fn arg))
            fns)))

(funcall (call-each (list #'third #'second #'first)) '(a b c))
;=> (C B A)
```

cl has the function `mapcan` which is basically  `nconc` + `mapcar` :

```
(mapcan #'reverse '((a b c)
                    (e f g)
                    (h i j)))
;=> (C B A G F E J I H)

(mapcan (call-each (list #'identity #'1+)) '(1 3 5 7 9))
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

unfortunately, `nconc`, which `mapcan` uses, is destructive:

```
(let ((data '((a b c)
              (d e f)
              (g h i))))
  ;;here be dragons
  (list (mapcan #'identity data)
        data))
;=> ((A B C D E F G H I) ((A B C D E F G H I) (D E F G H I) (G H I)))
```

`alexandria` to the rescue:

```
(let ((data '((a b c)
              (d e f)
              (g h i))))
  ;;safe version
  (list (alexandria:mappend #'identity data)
        data))
;=> ((A B C D E F G H I) ((A B C) (D E F) (G H I)))
```

note that using `mapcan` is more efficient, but unless you know exactly where
your data is coming from, and who owns it, `mappend` is the way to go.

so you could write:

```
(defun apply-functions (fs es)
  (when fs
    (alexandria:mappend (call-each fs) es))

(apply-functions (list #'identity #'1+) '(1 3 5 7 9))
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```